# Incomplete urls in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting results such as:

```
[crawler] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.hormelfoods.com/About/Legal/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/link.aspx?_id=EFFFBF3348524C6ABCD1C2775E7FDA93&_z=z> (referer: http://www.hormelfoods.com/About/Legal/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/link.aspx?_id=3FC7ECFD861B4F1AAF7BFD218236F983&_z=z)
```

I saw the page source of the referer: 
It shows this `<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=EFFFBF3348524C6ABCD1C2775E7FDA93&amp;_z=z">`

How to rectify this?

I have added a counter which keeps track of the number of pdfs parsed.

My parse_item function:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    for utype in self.url_types:
        links = []

        # if sel.select('/html/head/link[@type="application/pdf"]/@href').extract():
        #     links += sel.select('/html/head/link[@type="application/pdf"]/@href').extract()
        if sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "{0}")]/@href'.format(utype)).extract():
            links += sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "{0}")]/@href'.format(utype)).extract()

        if sel.xpath('/html/head/link[@type="application/{0}"]/@href'.format(utype)).extract():
            links += sel.xpath('/html/head/link[@type="application/{0}"]/@href'.format(utype)).extract()
        # if sel.select('/html/head/link[@type="application/x-pdf"]/@href').extract():
        #     links += sel.select('/html/head/link[@type="application/x-pdf"]/@href').extract()

        items = []
        self.cntr += len(links)
        if(self.cntr > 60):
          raise CloseSpider('links exceeded')
        for link in links:
           item = CrawlerItem()
           item['main'] = response.url
           base_url = get_base_url(response)
           item['url'] = urljoin(base_url,link)
           company = tldextract.extract(base_url)
           item['source'] = company.domain
           item['type'] = utype.upper()
           yield item

  def process_links(self,links):
    for i, w in enumerate(links):
        w.url = w.url.replace("../", "")
        links[i] = w
    return links
```

Comment: show your scrapy code

Comment: Where do you actually request/crawl a page? It seems here that your `parse_item` only parse the webpage you're on and keeps the found urls, but it's not the source of your weird log since it doesn't yield any request.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing entire spider code, I checked `http://www.hormelfoods.com` but nothing there seem to look like what's written here...